# replacing green pixels in a picture using java

Tags: java, methods, pixel

I have a picture and I am trying to remove all the green pixels. How do I do this using simple java and a 2D array?

So far, my code looks like this:

```
public void removeGreen() {

      Picture pic = new Picture("IMG_7320.JPG");
      Pixel pixel = null;
      for (int row = 0; row < pic.getHeight(); row++) {
          for (int col = 0; col < pic.getWidth(); col++) {
              pixel = getPixel(row,col);
              pixel.getColor();
              if(pixel.getRed() < 40 & pixel.getBlue() < 160 & pixel.getGreen() > 220) {
                  Color white = new Color(255,255,255);
                  pixel.setColor(white);
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

(Right now I am trying only replacing the green pixel with a white pixel because I'm not sure how to remove the pixel altogether.)

And the code in my main method that I am using to test the removeGreen() method,looks like this:

```
//method to test removeGreen

  public static void testRemoveGreen() {

      Picture me = new Picture("IMG_7320.JPG");
      me.explore();
      me.removeGreen();
      me.explore();
  }
```

---

---

So, my code now looks like this:

public void removeGreen(Picture pic) {

for (int row = 0; row < pic.getHeight(); row++) {

```
  for (int col = 0; col < pic.getWidth(); col++) {
      Pixel pixel = pic.getPixel(row,col);

      if((pixel.getRed() < 40) && (pixel.getBlue() < 160) && (pixel.getGreen() > 220)) {
          Color white = new Color(255,255,255);
          pixel.setColor(white);
      }
  }
```

}
}

and my main method is still the same. I still do not understand why the method is not working properly.

Comment: So you want to replace them with pixels from another image? Kind of a green screen? Clarify your question. You can never remove pixels from an image without resizing it by the way, best you can do is to make them transparent, assuming the image format you are working with supports alpha channel.

Comment: Also it seems to me you are iterating through an image `pic` while gathering data and modifying image `this`, make up your mind.

Answer (score 0):

The following makes clear that the passed `pic` parameter is altered.

```
  public static void removeGreen(Picture pic) {
      for (int row = 0; row < pic.getHeight(); row++) {
          for (int col = 0; col < pic.getWidth(); col++) {
              Pixel pixel = pic.getPixel(row,col);
              if (pixel.getRed() < 40 && pixel.getBlue() < 160
                      && pixel.getGreen() > 220) {
                  pixel.setColor(Color.white);
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

The `&&` is a short-cut AND: `x && y()` will not call y is x is false.

Mind the `pic.getPixel`. If `removeGreen` is intended as method of `Picture`, remove the parameter and the static keyword, and `pic.`.

```
public static void testRemoveGreen() {
    Picture me = new Picture("IMG_7320.JPG");
    me.explore();
    removeGreen(me);
    me.explore();
}
```

As the .jpg, JPEG, format does not have transparency, some colour like white is needed to be shown as "background."